# Do I need a client gui like pgAdmin4 to access an AWS RDS postgreSQL instance or is there a way I can access it via command line?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds

Is there a way to access an AWS RDS PostgreSQL instance via command line (`psql`)?

Or is it necessary to use a GUI client like pgAdmin to connect to the database?

Comment: A client is a client. Shouldn't matter what type of client as long as the connection can be opened.

Comment: AWS RDS postgres can absolutely be accessed using the `psql` shell interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a SQL client like DBeaver or you could use the command line tool “psql”. If you’re accessing a private RDS instance, you might have to likely use a bastion host to connect from outside the VPC.